# How to import txt file in SAS using infile command

Tags: sas

I 'm beginner in SAS and currently using SAS 9.1 I want to import txt file using infile command but it is giving error. My code is as follows

```
data sasdata.twenty;
```

`infile "C:\Users\Ravi Raghava\Desktop\Cricket.txt" firstobs=2;`

`input Position Runs    Sixes   Fours   balls;`

`run;`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seeing the error message would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do it by the following:

```
proc import datafile='data.txt'
     out=TableName
     replace;
     delimiter='09'x;
run;
```

It works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the default sas input (i.e. maybe space is used as a separator, guess whether I meant numeric or alpha-numeric and so on). You assume the SAS knows what it is doing. You know what happens when you assume.

Use a

```
 Length Positions $20 Runs Sixes Fours balls 8;
```

statement. That will at least make sure the first word is treated as alpha numeric and the rest as numbers. also use the

infile ..... dlm=',';

if you got a CSV file. or

```
infile ..... dlm='09'x;
```

if it is a tab separated file.